# Discord bot does not respond to my messages (js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, discord.js

Recently, I have made a Discord bot using **node.js** and **VS Code**. I can see my bot being online. However, **it does not respond to my messages**. (The bot has the required permissions.)
I could not understand the problem, I would be so delighted if you gave me a hand.

Here is my bot.js code

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
const config = require("./config.json");


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message' , message => {
    if(message === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }
})

client.login(config.token);
```

Here is my config.json code

```
{
 "token": "I wrote my token in here"
}
```

Comment: Add `console.log(message)` to your `client.on('message' , message => {` function and see what you got

Comment: You have to include the Guild Messages intent in your client's intents

Comment: I have taken a look at the documentation (https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#the-intents-bitfield) and tried to add Guild intents. I ended up like this :
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');

const myIntents = new IntentsBitField();
myIntents.add(IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildPresences, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });
Unfortunately , it did not work. 
Anyways, thank you all for help :D

Comment: How about adding both GuildMessages and MessageContent?
`const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });`

Comment: I had added both GuildMessages and MessageContent. I had taken a look at @ZsoltMeszaros 's link and I noticed something. I should have written `client.on('messageCreate'` instead of writing `client.on('message' `. Thanks, it is working now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code dosent work because your not checking for `message.content` which holds the message's content.

It should be somthing like this:

```js
client.on('message' , message => {
    if(message.content === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved the problem by writing `client.on('messageCreate'` (instead of `client.on('message'` . And also I added message.content, like you said.